# Cython code runs 125x slower when compiled against python 2 vs python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, cython

I have a big block of Cython code that is parsing [Touchstone files](http://ibis.org/interconnect_wip/touchstone_spec2_draft3.pdf) that I want to work with Python 2 and Python 3.  I'm using very C-style parsing techniques for what I thought would be maximum efficiency, including manually malloc-ing and free-ing `char*` instead of using `bytes` so that I can avoid the GIL.  When compiled using

```
python        3.5.2             0    anaconda
cython        0.24.1       py35_0    anaconda
```

I see speeds that I'm happy with, a moderate boost on small files (~20% faster) and a huge boost on large files (~2.5**x** faster).  When compiled against

```
python        2.7.12            0    anaconda
cython        0.24.1       py27_0    anaconda
```

It runs about 125x slower (~17ms in Python 3 vs ~2.2s in Python 2).  It's the exact same code compiled in different environments using a pretty simple `setuputils` script.  I'm not currently using NumPy from Cython for any of the parsing or data storage.

```
import cython
cimport cython

from cython cimport array
import array

from libc.stdlib cimport strtod, malloc, free
from libc.string cimport memcpy

ctypedef long long int64_t  # Really VS2008? Couldn't include this by default?

# Bunch of definitions and utility functions omitted

@cython.boundscheck(False)
cpdef Touchstone parse_touchstone(bytes file_contents, int num_ports):
    cdef:
        char c
        char* buffer = <char*> file_contents
        int64_t length_of_buffer = len(file_contents)
        int64_t i = 0

        # These are some cpdef enums
        FreqUnits freq_units
        Domain domain
        Format fmt
        double z0
        bint option_line_found = 0

        array.array data = array.array('d')
        array.array row = array.array('d', [0 for _ in range(row_size)])

    while i < length_of_buffer:
        c = buffer[i]  # cdef char c
        if is_whitespace(c):
            i += 1
            continue

        if is_comment_char(c):
            # Returns the last index of the comment
            i = parse_comment(buffer, length_of_buffer)
            continue

        if not option_line_found and is_option_leader_char(c):
            # Returns the last index of the option line
            # assigns values of all references passed in
            i = parse_option_line(
                buffer, length_of_buffer, i,
                &domain, &fmt, &z0, &freq_units)
            if i < 0:
                # Lots of boring code along the lines of
                # if i == some_int:
                #     raise Exception("message")
                # I did this so that only my top-level parse has to interact
                # with the interpreter, all the lower level functions have nogil
            option_line_found = 1

        if option_line_found:
            if is_digit(c):
                # Parse a float
                row[row_idx] = strtod(buffer + i, &end_of_value)
                # Jump the cursor to the end of that float
                i = end_of_value - p - 1
                row_idx += 1
                if row_idx == row_size:
                    # append this row onto the main data array
                    data.extend(row)
                    row_idx = 0

        i += 1

    return Touchstone(num_ports, domain, fmt, z0, freq_units, data)
```

I've ruled out a few things, such as type casts.  I also tested where the code simply loops over the entire file doing nothing.  Either Cython optimized that away or it's just really fast because it causes `parse_touchstone` to not even show up in a `cProfile/pstats` report.  I determined that it's not just the comment, whitespace, and option line parsing (not shown is the significantly more complicated keyword-value parsing) after I threw in a print statement in the last `if row_idx == row_size` block to print out a status and discovered that it's taking about 0.5-1 second (guesstimate) to parse a row with 512 floating point numbers on it.  That really should not take so long, especially when using `strtod` to do the parsing.  I also checked parsing just 2 rows' worth of values then jumping out of the while loop and it told me that parsing the comments, whitespace, and option line took up about 800ms (1/3 of the overall time), and that was for 6 lines of text totaling less than 150 bytes.

Am I just missing something here?  Is there a small trick that would cause Cython code to run 3 orders of magnitude slower in Python 2 than Python 3?

(Note: I haven't shown the full code here because I'm not sure if I'm allowed to for legal reasons and because it's about 450 lines total)

Comment: I suspect you need to construct a small test case that we can actually run and test.  Unless someone has worked with a similar task the problem isn't going to jump out just by reading the code.  How does the `cython` speed compare with pure Python (either version)?

Comment: @hpaulj unfortunately I'm not sure I can post a full working version due to legal reasons, but I will say that >99% of the file would be parsed in that last if block. The other implementation details aren't important, perhaps I can write a simple parser that only looks at the data. The speeds with pure Python are much better, 22ms on small files and about 1.2s for large files. My suspicion is that the libc functions might be what's causing the slowdown, although I wouldn't expect it to be that massive.

Comment: I wasn't thinking of the whole code; just a subset that demonstrates the problem.  Yes it takes more work for you.

Comment: Two thoughts. 1) it might be to do with memory allocation for your arrays (the line `data.extend(row)`?). It's possible that Python3 has made some improvements in this respect. Possibly make `data` a list of rows and then combine them together into a continuous array at the end (once you know how big it is) to avoid reallocating?

Comment: 2) I know there's [some differences](http://www.dabeaz.com/python/NewGIL.pdf) between Python2 and Python3 in how it does GIL switches. You haven't shown any GIL releases and reclaimings in your code, but your description implies you're trying to work without the GIL. If your real code has `with gil:`/`with nogil:` in then that might well perform differently. Perhaps try to make sure that you work with big `nogil` blocks rather than lots of small blocks.

Comment: @DavidW I wasn't able to take a look at it over the weekend, but discovered today that the culprit was strtod.  Apparently the version in VS2008 calculates the length of the string passed in each time it's called, and I was calling it with long strings resulting in an O(n^2) algorithm.  A simple wrapper around strtod that finds the beginning and end of the number, copies that into a small buffer, then parses it worked out well.  Now the Python 2 version is only a bit slower than the Python 3 version, and both are faster than the pure Python implementation by a good margin.

Comment: @bheklilr I did have a bit of a look but didn't get to the solution. A few quick notes: `array.extend(other_array)` is slightly slower in 3 vs 2. `array.array('d',other_array)` is significantly faster (~10x) in 3 (but you don't actually do it). (_Probably most useful_) you can index the arrays a lot faster if you view them as a typed memoryview: `double[::1] row = array.array('d', [0 for _ in range(row_size)])` will really speed up `row[row_idx] =`.

Comment: @DavidW I actually switched to using a `double*` and increased the size of row to cover many rows instead. This gave me quite a large performance boost, although I have to be more careful about memory management. I'm also using `array.extend_buffer`, since it has the compatible type for a pointer array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `strtod`, which is not [optimized in VS2008](http://www.ryanjuckett.com/programming/optimizing-atof-and-strtod/).  Apparently it internally calculates the length of the input string each time its called, and if you call it with a long string this will slow down your code considerably.  To circumvent this you have to write a wrapper around `strtod` to use only small buffers at a time (see the above link for one example of how to do this) or write your own `strtod` function.